# Reminder/Events is not being Notified

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-calendar, reminders

I want to set Reminder and events in android `Calender` by using below code i am able to see the events in android calendar but that event is not being notify or being alarm or anything.I am using `timpicker` for specific time.My problem is reminder and events are not notify or alarmed .Is there a problem in code or something else ?

```
   btnSetAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hours, int minutes) {

                            setEvents(hours,minutes);

                        }
                    }, hour, minute, false);
                    timePickerDialog.show();
                }
            });

 private void setReminders(Long eventID) {

        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        ContentValues reminders = new ContentValues();
        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID);
        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALARM);
        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES,5);
        Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/reminders");
        // event is added
        cr.insert(eventsUri, reminders);
    }

    private void setEvents(int hours, int minutes) {

        Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

        calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, calSet.getTimeInMillis());
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, calSet.getTimeInMillis() + 10000 );
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM,1);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "My Title");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Android Development");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID());

        Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
        // event is added
        Uri uri=cr.insert(eventsUri, values);


        // get the Event ID That is the Last element in the Uri
        Long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        Log.e(TAG, "" + eventID);
        setReminders(eventID);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue was with device Redmi Note 2 which does not provide proper `BroadcastListner` for `Calender` Events and need enable permission manually from the setting securities and need to set our app in `Auto-start` mode in order to listner the broadcast hence in short it was device related issue i have verified this code in other device which is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> The alarm method, as set on the server. METHOD_DEFAULT, METHOD_ALERT, METHOD_EMAIL, METHOD_SMS and METHOD_ALARM are possible values; the device will only process METHOD_DEFAULT and METHOD_ALERT reminders (the other types are simply stored so we can send the same reminder info back to the server when we make changes).

[RemindersColumns#METHOD](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/CalendarContract.RemindersColumns.html#METHOD:kotlin.String)

Try changing  `CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALARM` to `CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT`